# Swift navigation view not navigating to new page

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm using navigation view to navigate to a new page this is my code below which is not helping to naviate to the next page

```
LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
    ForEach( model.car, id: \.self) { item in
        NavigationLink(destination: CarDetailedView(carName: item.name, carImage: item.image)) {
            VStack{
                GridImageView(item.image,item.name)
                Text(item.name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you wrapped this into a `NavigationView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
NavigationStack {
    LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
        ForEach( model.car, id: \.self) { item in
            NavigationLink {
                CarDetailedView(carName: item.name, carImage: item.image)
            } label: {
                VStack{
                    GridImageView(item.image,item.name)
                    Text(item.name)
                }
            }

                    
        }
    }
}
```